# Creating React-Typescript project Failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I'm having an issue trying to use `create-react-app` with the `typescript` template, although it was working in the past. When trying to use `create-react-app` with no template i.e `JSX`, it sets up perfectly. I can't figure out what's going on.

Here is what I'm getting:

```
PS E:\GAD\React-Basics-Courses\Gad\React_Projects\React_Typescript> npx create-react-app my-typescript-project --template typescript


Creating a new React app in E:\GAD\React-Basics-Courses\Gad\React_Projects\React_Typescript\my-typescript-project.      

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template-typescript...


added 1455 packages in 4m

241 packages are looking for funding  run `npm fund` for details        

Installing template dependencies using npm...
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 @types/jest@^27.0.1 @types/node@^16.7.13 @types/react@^18.0.0 @types/react-dom@^18.0.0 typescript@^4.4.2 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed
PS E:\GAD\React-Basics-Courses\Gad\React_Projects\React_Typescript>
```

I have tried updating `npm`, `node`, and `tsc`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. I edited your question to make it easier to read. When you said "although it's not my first time", did you mean it was working in the past? I left that part as is in case I'm misunderstanding

Comment: Alright,
Yeah it was working in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Then retry your `npx create-react-app` command.

Comment: I just did, but still getting the same failed prompt

Answer (score 0):

Try running
`npm cache clean --force`
to clear the npm cache and then run the create-react-app command again.

If it's still not working, you can try creating the app without the template and adding TypeScript manually later:

`npx create-react-app my-typescript-project`

`cd my-typescript-project`

`npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom`

Comment: It didn't work, then i tried adding it manually, but the files are not in typescript extension.